# Property update

Tags: c#

I have created a component.
It has a designer form for change some property.
I am changing some property from designer form but
changes do not apply to propertygrid and designer.cs file unless move component.
What do I have to do for when I change a property in Designerform changes apply propertygrid and designer code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im not sure about, but i think your class have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. and in the set you have to fire this event.

As i said: Im not sure if this works for u. Just try it